# USB Type-C split to fast charge PD and use with car Android Auto

Tags: usb, charge

OK here is the image of the device and it is working, like users posted. There is one problem though, I cannot buy it anywhere.

[image: Android Auto splitter]

I want to make it out of cables directly, without using the board. I need a help for this to work. I already tried it and I have a problem recognizing a phone connected to PC, there is no connection because VBUS is not connected to USB A side of the connector. I cannot connect it because PD Fast charging is supplying greater voltage on VBUS than 5V while charging.

[image: My cables]

There is also a PD Buddy Wye adapter available on the internet but it is using all 3 Type C cables. The trick there is to use pull down 5.1kom resistors from CC1 and CC2 lines without using VBUS lines. But I need to use USB 2.0 A connector which doesn't have CC1 and CC2.

[image: PD Buddy Wye]

I also tried to add resistors on the A side from this schematic below, but with no luck. When the phone is not connected to cable I get PC to recognize that something is plugged into it, and device is malfunctioning because no phone is connected. When I connect phone, the PC doesn't recognize anything at all.

D+ voltage with phone connected is around 1V, and without phone connected is around 3.6V.

Can you help me assemble this cable to work?

[image: USB Pull Up]

Comment: please post a picture of the underside of the adapter board

Comment: I cannot find it anywhere. If I had the picture, I would have made it already. I need someone who bought it to take a picture of the underside.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is super late but here you go.

*Front of PCB*
[image]

<sup>Source: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lNSFo98YPnIDXND4Qn_iBad3ARNuq-qy/view?usp=sharing</sup>

*Back of PCB*
[image]

<sup>Source: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZK-GyNmtFY7PMOH447v0NOixivBW2coe/view?usp=drive_link</sup>

*How I think the wiring diagram is*
[image]

<sup>Source: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YGVctT_YS0jwWicaVV7MVvnb9A0Bo4ks/view?usp=sharing</sup>

I just can not confirm if the diagram is correct this is how it should be wired I traced it out but I am not 100% sure as I need someone who knows more than me about USB C standards to build a cable or replicate this board. You'll notice I have no USB ports I desoldered them to figure out the diagram as there are lines that run under the ports.

Comment: The D- can't connect to CC1 and D+ can't connect to SBU. There must be an error in the diagram.